# Android webview not rendering correctly

Tags: android, webview, visualization, android-webview

I have been having a strange error when visualizing some pages with a webview. I have found this problem when using a Samsung Tablet model SGH - I957 running Honeycomb 3.1 (On previous versions of android and other devices, I haven't seen this problem).

The problem happens when visualizing pages which have input fields (Username or password). When pressing several times one of these inputfields, the page turns to black, leaving just the inputfield 'correctly' visualized. But when trying to scroll the view, the page visualizes normally again, as if scrolling caused the view to correctly render itself.

I have tried this on two sites: Facebook and Twitter

To reproduce this problem it's enough to have a simple activity with a webview (with web view client). javascript is enabled.

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    return false;
    }
});

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com/");
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem with a samsung tablet running 3.x and got it working enabling hardware acceleration in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
   android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```