# Tumblr not rendering properly in WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

Hi I am testing out OAuth authorisation in my app for various sites using a pop-up dialog with an embedded webview where the user can log in and authorise. Works fine for twitter and foursquare. However Tumblr doesn't render properly for some reason.

When I put the authorisation url into a desktop browser everything works fine. However on my phone, whether on a browser on the phone proper or in a webview in my app, all i get is the title "tumblr. Get Ready. It's time. Push the button" plus a blue rectangle and a grey rectangle underneath which I can't interact with.

I have tried putting on javascript settings ([Android webview not rendering html content correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174991/android-webview-not-rendering-html-content-correctly)), switching hardware acceleration on and off ([Android webview not rendering correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760003/android-webview-not-rendering-correctly)), or setting storage options ([Problems loading mobile.twitter in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856814/problems-loading-mobile-twitter-in-webview)). Nothing works. Would be very grateful if anyone has any ideas!

Many thanks,
Riz

Edit: I suspect it's something to do with Chrome n the phone rather than my code as Chrome itself doesn't render Tumblr properly it seems.

Anyway, here is the code I'm using:

```
public class FragmentOAuthUrlBrowser extends Fragment {
    private static final String REQUEST =     "com.chdryra.android.reviewer.View.ActivitiesFragments.FragmentViewUrlBrowser.url";

    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_review_url_browser;
    private static final int WEB_VIEW = R.id.web_view;

    private OAuthRequest mRequest;

    public static FragmentOAuthUrlBrowser newInstance(OAuthRequest request) {
        return FactoryFragment.newFragment(FragmentOAuthUrlBrowser.class, REQUEST, request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) mRequest = args.getParcelable(REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);

        WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(WEB_VIEW);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new OAuthWebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(mRequest.getAuthorisationUrl());

        return v;
    }

    private class OAuthWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            mRequest.setCallbackResult(view.getUrl());
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }
```

Here is how it renders:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I implemented TumblrLogin. Playing around with Hardware acceleration and storage is not required.

Enable the JavaScript using

```
//Enable JS support on web browser - important since TumblrLogin utilises JS components to show / hide UI
//Login page will not show up properly if this is not done
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Set a new WebView client to capture redirections. I found a normal WebViewClient to do the trick. I guess the ChromeWebViewClient should work find too.

That's all. No other customization is required. Hope you're pointing the correct URLs.

`<string name="tumblr_request">https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token</string>
 <string name="tumblr_access">https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token</string>
 <string name="tumblr_auth">https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize</string>`

Comment: Thanks. I have java script enabled but doesn't help unfortunately. I get to the correct webpage (copy and paste url into browser) just doesn't render properly.

Comment: Would you post your code and screenshot of the render please?

Comment: I come across that screen on & off. I just let it load & in time, the blue box turns into the Login button and all is right with the world.

Try using [Loglr](https://github.com/dakshsrivastava/Loglr) & check if you still get stuck at that point. If you do, I think its about the phone & browser than the code.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the help and tips